# Repository not autowiring with MongoDB and spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am having some issues with trying to autowire a repository into the main class. I am getting the following error :-

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in com.talkable_bm234.App required a bean of type 'com.talkable_bm234.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.talkable_bm234.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

Here are my files, I've been able to succeed with this before but struggling to set it up with Mongo:

**App.java**

```
package com.talkable_bm234;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableReactiveMongoRepositories;

import com.talkable_bm234.domain.User;
import com.talkable_bm234.repository.UserRepository;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories({"com.talkable_bm234.repository"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.talkable_bm234"})
public class App {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner administrators(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {        
            // Add administrator account type on boot
            logger.info("preparing to add admin accounts...");
            final User administratorA = new User("John", "Doe", "adminA@admins.co.uk", "12345", "ADMIN");
            final User administratorB = new User("Wendy", "Doe", "adminB@admins.co.uk", "12345", "ADMIN");
            userRepository.saveAll(Flux.just(administratorA, administratorB)).subscribe();          
        };
    }   
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package com.talkable_bm234.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.talkable_bm234.domain.User;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 *  Reactive Repository class for handling users
 * @author Ben
 */

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<User, String> {

    //Find by Email Address
    Mono<User> findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);

}
```

**MongoConfig.java**

```
package com.talkable_bm234.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureAfter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableReactiveMongoRepositories;

import com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClients;

/**
 * Reactive MongoDB Configuration for Cloud Database
 * @author Ben
 *
 */

@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public abstract class MongoConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {


    //Values taken from 'application.properties'
    //------------------------------------------
    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.username}")
    private String  userName;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.password}")
    private String  password;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
    private String  database;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String  host;

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    private Integer port;
    //----------------------------------------

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return database;
  }

  @Bean
  @DependsOn("embeddedMongoServer")
  public MongoClient mongoClient() {
      return (MongoClient) MongoClients.create(String.format("mongodb://%s:%d", host, port));
  }


  protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
    return "com.talkable_bm234.domain";
  }
}
```

**User.java - Lombok Getters & Setters**

```
package com.talkable_bm234.domain;

import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.PersistenceConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NonNull;
import lombok.Setter;


/**
 * Domain Class for a registered User.
 * User Types: "USER", "PRESENTER", "ADMIN"
 * @author Ben
 * MongoDB & Lombok Annotations
 */

//Name of collection, user objects are mapped to! ->
@Document(collection="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Getter @Setter
    private long ObjID;

    @Getter @Setter @NonNull
    private String firstName;

    @Getter @Setter @NonNull
    private String lastName;

    @Getter @Setter @NonNull
    @Indexed(name="emailAddress", unique=true)
    private String emailAddress;

    @Getter @Setter @NonNull
    private String password;

    @Getter @Setter @NonNull
    private String type;

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public User(String firstName, String lastName,
            String emailAddress, String password, String type) {

        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.password = password;
        this.type = type;
    }


    public User() {}

}
```

Any ideas ?
Regards,
Ben

Comment: what happens if you comment out @Repository ?

Comment: `
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Field userRepository in com.talkable_bm234.App required a bean named 'reactiveMongoTemplate' that could not be found.

Consider defining a bean named 'reactiveMongoTemplate' in your configuration.`  Looks promising! I guess @Repository isn't needed for MongoDB then!

Comment: Why are you defining the `interface` as `@Repository`? And where is the actual repository `class` that `implements UserRepository `?

Comment: You have `@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories` declared twice. I think you only need it on `MongoConfig`, and without a package specified.. Also, you shouldn't need `@Repository` on yours because it is extending `ReactiveMongoRepository` and should be detected already. What happens with these changes?

Comment: Thanks, this works! I think there was another error resising in my .settings folder concerning Web Facet 2.5 or so, this had something to do with it also I believe! Thanks :)